# CDFs of indicator random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Consider two events $A$ and $B$ in the probability space and let $X = 1_A$ and $Y = 1_B$ be
> their indicator random variables. Find their joint CDF.

So here's what I know and have tried:

A random variable is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$, so $X(\omega) = 1$ if $\omega\in A$ and $0$ otherwise (it's the indicator). Similarly for $Y$. The joint CDF is supposed to look like this:
$$P(X\le x, Y\le y) = P((X\le x)\cap(Y\le y))$$
Now what's $P(X\le x)$?

$X$ can take only two values, i.e. $0,1$. I would expect $P(X\le x) = 0$ if $x < 0$. Also $P(X\le x) = 1$ if $x\ge 1$. What happens in between, it's quite confusing!

One thing that comes to mind is that the random variable $Z = 1_{A\cap B}$ would indicate when $A$ and $B$ occur together. Does that help?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so, that's all the information I have. Can we say nothing about the joint CDF? Also what about the individual CDFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is a random variable taking values $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $P(A^{c})$ and $P(A)$ respectively. The CDF $F_X$ of $X$ is given by $F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)=0$ if $x <0$, $F_X(x)=P(A^{c})$ if $F_X(x)=0\leq x <1$ and $1$ if $x \geq 1$. Similarly for $F_Y$.

$F_{X,Y} (x,y)=P(X \leq x, Y\leq y)$ and this is

$0$ of $x <0$ or $y <0$,

$1$ if $x \geq 1$ and $y\geq 1$,

$P(A^{c}\cap B^{c})$ if $0 \leq x <1$ and $0\leq y <1$,

$P(A^{c})$ if $0 \leq x <1$ and $y \geq 1$ and

$P(B^{c})$ if $0 \leq y <1$ and $x \geq 1$.